# Which of the following methods tells Absolute stability & which method tells Relative Stability? Bode Plot, Routh Hurwitz, Root Locus, Nyquist PlotC

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, nyquist-plot, root-locus

Which of the following methods tells Absolute stability & which method tells Relative Stability?
I. Bode Plot
ii. Routh Hurwitz
iii. Root Locus
iv. Nyquist Plot

What i think is the following correct me if I am wrong.
I. Bode Plot (tells only relative stability)
ii. Routh Hurwitz (tells only absolute stability)
iii. Root Locus (tells about both stabilites)
iv. Nyquist Plot (tells about both stabilites)

Comment: Is this an exam question?

Comment: A question appeared to me in exam similar to this....

Comment: So, what was your answer? then people may help with the answer.

Comment: What's the difference between absolute and relative stability?

Comment: Relative stability and absolute stability are not two different "kinds" of stability. Absolute stability is a binary thing, is the system stable or not?

Relative stability will tell you, if your system is stable, by how much can you increase the gain of the system or the phase lag of the system before it becomes unstable?

Comment: Well, it seems like you know the answer so, post what you know either as a formal answer or as information in your question.

Comment: I dont think all of the methods tell both of the things.

Comment: This is well documented on every good control system textbooks.

Comment: R-H  criteria only gives the necessary criteria for absolute results.

Comment: I agree with that. R-H will only tell you if a system is stable or unstable but it won't tell you how stable it is.